# Timeline disappears after syncing with MS Project Pro

Tags: list, ms-project, timeline

I am using a free Project Management template sponsored by BrightWork.

After syncing my task list with MS Project Pro, my timeline disappears from the List page as well as the homepage.

[image: Disappearing timeline]
 [image: Disappearing Timeline on home page, greyed out option on task bar]

The same issue happens when i set the item limit from the default value of  to 9999.

Really hope someone is able to answer this